# Replace failing LVM disk with root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, ubuntu-18.04

This was my first setup so it's a bit messy. Extremely small root volume (3.9GB) which I'd like to increase but the problem right now is that the disk is failing and I need to replace it.

```
root@boxboxbox:/data# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               903M     0  903M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              187M  1.1M  186M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  3.7G  1.2M 100% /
tmpfs                              934M     0  934M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              934M     0  934M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc2                          976M  228M  682M  26% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg01-lv01              5.4T  3.9T  1.3T  77% /data
tmpfs                              187M     0  187M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0                          94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/sdd1                          466G  403G   63G  87% /temp
/dev/loop1                          97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
```

```
root@boxboxbox:/data# sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME                      FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT      LABEL
loop0                     squashfs     93.9M /snap/core/9066
loop1                     squashfs       97M /snap/core/9665
sda                                     1.8T
└─sda1                    LVM2_member   1.8T
  └─vg01-lv01             ext4          5.5T /data
sdb                                     1.8T
└─sdb1                    LVM2_member   1.8T
  └─vg01-lv01             ext4          5.5T /data
sdc                                     1.8T
├─sdc1                                    1M
├─sdc2                    ext4            1G /boot
└─sdc3                    LVM2_member   1.8T
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4            4G /
  └─ubuntu--vg-sdc3       LVM2_member   1.8T
    └─vg01-lv01           ext4          5.5T /data
sdd                                   465.8G
└─sdd1                    ntfs        465.8G /temp
```

`sdc` is the one failing and I'd like to replace it with a 4TB drive. The thing is can I just pvmove it or will I mess everything up?

Answer (score 3):

You can just pvmove the root file system, that is the easy bit.

What you also need to take care of is booting, because the /boot partition is not inside LVM, which is easier done from a rescue system.